# Read and join multiple remote files PHP

Tags: php

I'm using this code to read multiple remote files:

```
$filters = [ "https://example.com/file.txt", "https://example.com/file1.txt", "https://example.com/file3.txt" ]

function parseFilterLists( $filters )
  {
    foreach( $filters as $filter ){
      $file =  file_get_contents( $filter );
      $parsed = preg_replace( '/!.*/', '', $file );
      $parsed = preg_replace( '/\|\|([\w\d]+(?:\.[\w]+)+)(?:[\^\$=~].*)/', '*://*.$1/*', $parsed ); 
    }
    $output = array_filter( explode( "\n", $parsed ), function($url){
      return preg_match('/^\*:\/\/\*\.[\w\d-]+\.[\w]+\/\*$/', $url);
    });
    return array_values(array_unique($output));
  }
```

I've noticed that the output content is truncated like just one file is processed, but what I need is to join the three files to manipulate them. How I can achive this?

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate strings?

Comment: We need to see the content of the files.

Comment: The scope of $parsed is limited to the foreach loop, you're only getting the last file in the $filters list.

Comment: @RobRuchte ok,so how I can solve this withoud repeating the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of `$parsed` is limited to the foreach loop, so `$output` only contains results from the last iteration of the loop. You should define `$output` before the loop, and append the results of each iteration to it.

```
<?php
$filters = ["https://example.com/file.txt", "https://example.com/file1.txt", "https://example.com/file3.txt"];

function parseFilterLists($filters)
{
    // Define a buffer for the output
    $output = [];
    foreach ($filters as $filter)
    {
        $file   = file_get_contents($filter);
        $parsed = preg_replace('/!.*/', '', $file);
        $parsed = preg_replace('/\|\|([\w\d]+(?:\.[\w]+)+)(?:[\^\$=~].*)/', '*://*.$1/*', $parsed);

        // Get the output for the file we're working on in this iteration
        $currOutput = array_filter(explode("\n", $parsed), function ($url) {
            return preg_match('/^\*:\/\/\*\.[\w\d-]+\.[\w]+\/\*$/', $url);
        });

        // Append the output from the current file to the output buffer
        $output = array_merge($output, $currOutput);
    }

    // Return the unique results
    return array_unique($output);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and the delucidation about the `$parsed` var, I suppose that I can apply this also to a class method by defining the `$output` variable on top of the file right?

Comment: You're welcome, yes, you can do that, you would just need to refer to it as $this->output inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will work as you want

```
$filters = [ 
  "https://example.com/file.txt", "https://example.com/file1.txt", "https://example.com/file3.txt"
];

function parseFilterLists( $filters )
  {
    $files = [];
    foreach( $filters as $filter ){
      $files[] = file_get_contents( $filter );
    }
    $parsed = preg_replace( '/!.*/', '', implode("\n", $files));
    $parsed = preg_replace( '/\|\|([\w\d]+(?:\.[\w]+)+)(?:[\^\$=~].*)/', '*://*.$1/*', $parsed); 
    $output = array_filter( explode( "\n", $parsed ), function($url){
      return preg_match('/^\*:\/\/\*\.[\w\d-]+\.[\w]+\/\*$/', $url);
    });
    return array_values(array_unique($output));
  }
```

Comment: Why you've used implode function?